# How to make a MTKView inside a NSScrollView show the scrollbars

Tags: cocoa, metal, nsscrollview

If I resize the window to be smaller than the metal view I can see the scrollbars for a second but I cannot click on them nor they stay visible. Do you know how I can change this behavior? I would expect the scrollbars to be visible and clickable as long as the window is smaller than the metal view.

```
    nsview = gdk_quartz_window_get_nsview(window);

    NSScrollView *scroll_view = [[NSScrollView alloc]initWithFrame: [nsview frame]];
    [scroll_view setBorderType: NSNoBorder];
    [scroll_view setHasVerticalScroller: YES];
    [scroll_view setHasHorizontalScroller: YES];
    [scroll_view setAutoresizingMask: NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];

    [nsview addSubview: scroll_view];

    self->clip_view = [[DvFlippedClipView alloc]initWithFrame: [nsview frame]];
    [scroll_view setContentView: self->clip_view];

    self->mtk_view = [[MTKView alloc]initWithFrame: [nsview frame]
                                            device: self->device];

    self->mtk_view.framebufferOnly = YES;
    self->mtk_view.autoResizeDrawable = NO;

    self->mtk_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    self->mtk_view_delegate = [[DvMetalViewDelegate alloc] init: self->mtk_view];
    self->mtk_view.delegate = self->mtk_view_delegate;

    [scroll_view setDocumentView: self->mtk_view];
```

From a different callback I do the following:

```
    [self->mtk_view setBounds:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height)];
    [self->mtk_view setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height)];
    self->mtk_view.drawableSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false for the `MTKView`? And does it help to remove that line?

Comment: I think I added it as one of my attempts to fix this issue. Removing that line changes nothing on the problem.

Comment: Does scrolling itself actually work (using a mouse wheel, multi-touch mouse, or trackpad)?

Comment: It does not, the scrollbars just show up during the resize of the window for a second then they go away and moving the mouse around the border does not show the scrollbars until I resize again...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem yesterday, and I suspect the strange scroller behavior and lack of scrolling altogether may be stemming from what I suspect your problem is. Hopefully it will at least enlighten your or someone else if you haven't already found an answer.

My view hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

The problem was that I had set MTKView as the view property of CenterTopViewController, rather than the Bordered Scroll View. Doing that, for all practical intents and purposes, removed MTKView from the hierarchy and set it so that its superview property pointed to the split view in which all of this resides. The scroll view did not seem to be part of the responder chain, and was never handling any scroll events (or at least not in any meaningful way).

Setting the scroll view as the view property of the view controller fixed everything.

P.S.
If you're confused as to why there is an unnecessary view above the MTKView, it's just a result of almost desperate attempts to uncover the problem before I figured it out. I haven't gotten around to fixing it yet.